# Excel Macro - Find a specified value in one column and replace with all the contents of another column

Tags: excel, vba

I am really really a newbie when it comes to Macros, but I believe it would help solve a problem.

I have two columns, the first column has a full description sentence, where one part of the sentence has a value called {Brand}. The second column has the names of all the brands (eg. Nike, Adidas, Puma, etc.)

All I want to do, is to replace and description that has {brand} in the first column, with all names from the second column.

So something like this

"This {brand} shoe is ..."

with

"This Nike shoe is ..."

Any help would be so appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a macro for this.

Let's say Cell A1 has "This {brand} shoe is ..." and B1 has "Nike" then type this formula in cell C1

=REPLACE(A1,SEARCH("{brand}",A1,1),7,B1)

For rest, simply copy it down.